# Firebase HTTPS Cloud Function Returning 404 in Production

Tags: function, firebase, cloud, google-cloud-functions

I have pushed a very basic HTTP Cloud Function to Firebase and am getting a `404` when trying to access in browser or via Postman.  The function works locally, via both `firebase serve` and via various tests that I've written using the `firebase-functions-test` SDK.

```
// import function libraries and initialize admin app
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
var admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)

// push data to a specific database
var pushData = (path) => (payload) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    admin.database().ref(path).push(payload).then(snapshot => {
      resolve(snapshot)
    }).catch((error) => {
      reject(error)
    })
  })
}

// github webhook endpoint
exports.postGitHubEvent = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  // handle invalid request method
  if (request.method !== 'POST') {
    return response.send(405, 'Only POST Requests Are Accepted')
  }
  // push request body to database
  var event = request.body
  var writeData = pushData('github')(event)

  // return write promise
  return writeData.then(
    result => response.send(200, `Successfully Pushed Github Event: ${result}`),
    error => response.send(500, `Error in Pushing GitHub Event: ${error}`)
  )
})
```

Comment: Hi Grant, and welcome to SO. Just to be sure, are you trying to hit the endpoint given by the deployment process (_and visible in the Firebase console, on the Functions tab_)? Or are you just adding `/postGitHubEvent` to the end of your URL and expecting it to trigger?

Comment: Hi Jeremy!  I am hitting the endpoint given by Firebase console: `https://us-central1-{projectName}.cloudfunctions.net/postGitHubEvent`

Comment: Returns this in browser / Postman.  I've essentially copied code from another project that _does_ correctly function, so I'm pretty confused here.  Error I'm getting:      <b>404.</b>
    <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
    <p>The requested URL was not found on this server.  
        <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>

Comment: It's worth noting that I also have an onCreate function up and running in the project, and that _is_ functioning correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered.  My firebase project ID has two hiphens in it and was customized (edited) upon the creation of the project.  Kept one hiphen in the project name / project ID and now it functions correctly...